# How can one generate an open-ended sequence of low-discrepancy points in 3D?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'd like a low-discrepancy sequence of points over a 3D-hypercube $[-1,1]^3$, but don't want to have to commit to a fixed number $n$ of points beforehand, that is  just see how the numerical integration estimates develop with increasing numbers of low-discrepancy points.

I'd like to avoid have to start all over again, if the results with a fixed $n$ are unsatisfactory. Of course, one could just employ random numbers, but then the convergence behavior would be poorer.

"A sequence of n-tuples that fills n-space more uniformly than uncorrelated random points, sometimes also called a low-discrepancy sequence. Although the ordinary uniform random numbers and quasirandom sequences both produce uniformly distributed sequences, there is a big difference between the two." (mathworld.wolfram.com/QuasirandomSequence.html)

This question has also just been put on the mathematica.stack.exchange
(https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143457/how-can-one-generate-an-open-ended-sequence-of-low-discrepancy-points-in-3d)

Since in his answer below, Martin Roberts advances a very interesting, appealing approach to the open-ended low-discrepancy problem, I’d like to indicate an (ongoing) implementation of his approach I’ve just reported in https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09040 . In sec. XI (p. 19) and Figs. 5 and 6 there, I analyze two problems—one with sampling dimension $d=36$ and one with $d=64$—both using the parameter $\bf{\alpha}_0$ set to 0 and also to $\frac{1}{2}$. To convert the quasi-uniformly distributed points yielded by the Roberts’ algorithm to quasi-uniformly distributed normal variates, I use the code developed by Henrik Schumacher in his answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181099/can-i-use-compile-to-speed-up-inversecdf

Comment: I would pick an irrational number $\alpha$ and use $(\alpha n, \alpha n^2, \alpha n^3)$ mod $2$.

Comment: Thanks, Mercio! Seems quite elegant! Any arguments as to it properties (relevant literature)? Of course, to fit the [-1,1]^3 hypercube, one should subtract 1 from your formula.

Comment: well there is a theorem saying that any polynomial in $n$ with at least one irrational (and non-constant ?) coefficient is equireparted but I'm not sure that's strong enough to prove what you want.

Answer (score 3):

*As the OP cross-posted this [question from Math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231391/how-can-one-generate-an-open-ended-sequence-of-low-discrepancy-points-in-3d/2845473#2845473), I have also cross-posted the answer that I wrote there.*

## #

The simplest traditional solution to the $d$-dimensional which provides quite good results in 3-dimensions is to use the Halton sequence based on the first three primes numbers (2,3,5). The Halton sequence is a generalization of the 1-dimensional Van der Corput sequence and merely requires that the three parameters are pairwise-coprime.  Further details can be found at the Wikipedia article: ["Halton Sequence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence).

An alternative sequence you could use is the generalization of the Weyl / Kronecker sequence. This sequence also typically uses the first three prime numbers, however, in this case they are chosen merely because the square root of these numbers is irrational.

However, I have recently written a detailed blog post, ["The Unreasonable effectiveness of Quasirandom Sequences](http://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/), on how to easily create an open-ended low discrepancy sequences in arbitrary dimensions, that is:

- algebraically simpler
- faster to compute
- produces more consistent outputs
- suffers less technical issues

than existing existing low discrepancy sequences, such as the Halton and Kronecker sequences.

The solution is an additive recurrence method (modulo 1) which generalizes the 1-Dimensional problem whose solution depends on the Golden Ratio. The solution to the $d$-dimensional problem, depends on a special constant $\phi_d$, where $\phi_d$ is the unique positive root of $x^{d+1}=x+1$.

For $d=1$,  $ \phi_1 = 1.618033989... $, which is the canonical golden ratio.

For $d=2$, $ \phi_2 = 1.3247179572... $, which  is often called the plastic constant, and has some beautiful properties. This value was conjectured to most likely be the optimal value for a related two-dimensional problem [Hensley, 2002]. Jacob Rus has posted a beautiful visualization of this 2-dimensional low discrepancy sequence, which can be found [here](https://beta.observablehq.com/@jrus/plastic-sequence).

And finally specifically relating to your question, for $d=3$, $ \phi_3 = 1.2207440846... $

With this special constant in hand, the calculation of the $n$-th term is now extremely simple and fast to calculate:

$$ R: \mathbf{t}_n = \pmb{\alpha}_0 + n \pmb{\alpha}  \; (\textrm{mod} \; 1),  \quad n=1,2,3,... $$
$$ \textrm{where} \quad \pmb{\alpha} =(\frac{1}{\phi_d}, \frac{1}{\phi_d^2},\frac{1}{\phi_d^3},...\frac{1}{\phi_d^d}), $$

Of course, the reason this is called a recurrence sequence is because the above definition is equivalent to 
$$ R: \mathbf{t}_{n+1} =  \mathbf{t}_{n} +  \pmb{\alpha}  \; (\textrm{mod} \; 1) $$

In nearly all instances, the choice of $\pmb{\alpha}_0 $ does not change the key characteristics, and so for reasons of obvious simplicity, $\pmb{\alpha}_0 =\pmb{0}$ is the usual choice. However, there are some arguments, relating to symmetry, that suggest that $\pmb{\alpha}_0=\pmb{1/2}$  is a better choice.

Specifically for $d=3$, $\phi_3 = 1.2207440846... $ and so for $\pmb{\alpha}_0= (1/2,1/2,1/2) $, 
$$\pmb{\alpha} = (0.819173,0.671044,0.549700) $$ and so the first 5 terms of the canonical 3-dimensional sequence are:

1. (0.319173, 0.171044, 0.0497005)
2. (0.138345, 0.842087, 0.599401)
3. (0.957518, 0.513131, 0.149101)
4. (0.77669, 0.184174, 0.698802)
5. (0.595863, 0.855218, 0.248502)
   ...

Of course, this sequence ranges between [0,1], and so to convert to a range of [-1,1], simply apply the linear transformation $ x:= 2x-1 $. The result is

1. (-0.361655, -0.657913, -0.900599)
2. (-0.72331, 0.684174, 0.198802)
3. (0.915035, 0.0262616, -0.701797)
4. (0.55338, -0.631651, 0.397604)
5. (0.191725, 0.710436, -0.502995),...

The Mathematica Code for creating this sequence is as follows:

```
f[n_] := x /. FindRoot[x^(1 + n) == x + 1, {x, 1}];

d = 3;
n = 5

gamma = 1/f[d];
alpha = Table[gamma^k , {k, Range[d]}]
ptsPhi =  Map[FractionalPart, Table[0.5 + i alpha, {i, Range[n]}], {2}]
```

Similar Python code is

```
# Use Newton-Rhapson-Method
def gamma(d):
    x=1.0000
    for i in range(20):
        x = x-(pow(x,d+1)-x-1)/((d+1)*pow(x,d)-1)
    return x

d=3
n=5

g = gamma(d)
alpha = np.zeros(d)                 
for j in range(d):
    alpha[j] = pow(1/g,j+1) %1
z = np.zeros((n, d))    
for i in range(n):
    z = (0.5 + alpha*(i+1)) %1

print(z)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You found an old unanswered question to answer. I hope the OP still needs this and is pleased.

Comment: I hope so, but even if it is too late, i thought there might be value for other people who are wondering the same question. ;)

Comment: I'm making use (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358222/can-should-one-generate-ginibre-ensembles-of-random-matrices-using-low-discrepan/358461#358461) of the procedure suggested by Martin Roberts (now with $d=36$ and 64), and I am strongly impressed by its performance (as well as its elegance).

Comment: Follow-up question: At each iteration, my algorithm requires a 64-dimensional point. I use 32 of the points to generate one matrix, and the other 32, a second matrix, which I then combine by matrix multiplication for the final result I employ. I can generate one 64-dimensional point, or two 32-dimensional ones to use. Might there be any pros and cons for such a choice? The two 32-dimensional ones would, of course, have to be "independent" (different $s_0$'s ?) Any motivation to "scramble" a 64-dimensional choice?

Comment: If you know the required total number of iterations upfront, then the definitive answer is described in my blog post in the section "Multiscale low discrepancy" (with 2 classes). 
http://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/
That is, calculate 2N points from a 32-dimensional sequence. The first N points are for matrix A, and the next N points are for matrix B. 
Note this technique only works for this particular phi-based low discrepancy sequence method.

Comment: (contd) 
However, if you do not know the number of iterations upfront, the I do not know of any ideal solution.

Definitely do not use the first 32 components of a 64D sequence for Matrix A, and the last 32 components for Matrix B, as the components are highly correlated.

I do not think that scrambling improves anything.

Thus, the most reasonable (but still not ideal) solution is to use to independent 32D sequences, each with a different s0.

However, for unknown N, I do not know how to pick two two seeds in a manner that is consistently better than using two random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

another good solution to get an open-ended sequence is using the Halton method. It is also very easy to implement, even for any dimension! For d<8 it has usually good properties, beyond this more difficult will typically outperform Halton.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was posed in April, 2017. Now, a few days ago, I extended the question

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143457/how-can-one-generate-an-open-ended-sequence-of-low-discrepancy-points-in-3d

to express concern about the possible relevance of the (Mathematica) WorkingPrecision setting to the reliability--noting that the command FractionalPart is applied at each iteration--of the quasirandom results generated by the algorithm given by Martin Roberts in his answer to the original question.

My test example concerned the estimation--in a 3D context--of nine values, 
four of which are known from prior considerations. (In the question, I stated three, but then realized that a fourth also is known.) The four values, one anticipates the quasirandom procedure will converge to are 
(see https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.06745)
\begin{equation}
\left\{\frac{1}{36},\frac{8 \pi }{27 \sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{81} \left(27+\sqrt{3} \log \left(97+56
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right),\frac{2}{81} \left(4 \sqrt{3} \pi -21\right)\right\} \approx
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\{0.027777777777777777778,0.53742203384717565944, 0.44597718463717723667, \
0.018903515328657140917\}.
\end{equation}
In the estimation, I employed three billion 3D points, recording the results at intervals of one hundred million. A plot showing the 
four sets of results, along with the constant/target line 1,  is

[image: Estimation results]

The yellow curve corresponds to the estimation of 0.44597718463717723667. The estimation of 0.02777777777777777777 is clearly the best of the four, hovering close to the constant line of 1. The blue curve corresponds to 0.53742203384717565944, while the (most highly fluctuating) green is for the smallest target value of 0.018903515328657140917.

These results were obtained using WorkingPrecision->20.

Then, due to my concerns, I undertook a repetition of the calculations, but now employing WorkingPrecision->40. After seven hundred million iterations, the results were identical to those obtained using WorkingPrecision->20. (Somewhat curiously, the computational time decreased by about $7\%$.)  I am continuing to three billion iterations, as before, and will update this answer if I detect any deviations from the first set of results. Also, if there are no differences after the three billion, I will also note that.

But, as of now, it seems that the WorkingPrecision setting to 20 was certainly adequate for the task at hand.

Let me also note that as each quasirandom 3D point (Q1, Q2, Q3) is generated, I test to see if it satisfies the constraint
\begin{equation}
\text{Q1}>0\land \text{Q2}>0\land \text{Q3}>0\land \text{Q1}+3 \text{Q2}+2 \text{Q3}<1.
\end{equation}
If it does not, it is discarded from further consideration. Only $\frac{1}{36} \approx 0.027777777777777777778$ should satisfy the constraint (and as the plot shows, this is certainly the case).

UPDATE:

I now have two sets of results, both based on three billion iterations, the first having employed WorkingPrecision->20, the second, WorkingPrecision->40.

For each point (Q1,Q2,Q3) generated, I tested--as indicated above--whether it satisfied the constraint
\begin{equation}
\text{Q1}>0\land \text{Q2}>0\land \text{Q3}>0\land \text{Q1}+3 \text{Q2}+2 \text{Q3}<1.
\end{equation}
In both cases, the SAME number--83,333,308--of points passed the test, giving a probability of 0.0277777693333333, that is, very close to $\frac{1}{36}$, that a simple 3D integration yields.

Then, for each of these 83,333,308 points I tested whether it satisfied the further ("PPT"--"positive partial transpose") constraint
\begin{equation}
\text{Q1}^2+3 \text{Q1} \text{Q2}+(3 \text{Q2}+\text{Q3})^2<2 \text{Q1} \text{Q3}+3
   \text{Q2}.
\end{equation}

Now, the two number of points passing the further test were DIFFERENT,
but almost identical. With WorkingPrecision->20, the number was 44,785,111
and with WorkingPrecision->40, it was two greater, that is, 44,785,113. (Let me note that the ratio [$R_1$] of the latter number to the common number 83,333,308, gives a further ratio [$R_2$] to the known value $\frac{8 \pi }{27 \sqrt{3}} \approx 0.53742203384718$ of 0.9999990427, closer to 1--as we would hope/expect--than the former [lesser WorkingPrecision] number of 44,785,111.)

I will now continue on my analyses with the higher setting of WorkingPrecision.